# Loading image before php script

Tags: php, image, loading

Hi guys I have a form which after submitted links to a script "sendeveryone.php" this script takes quite a while to finish so I want to show a loading image while that is being done, how could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Show us some of the code you already have.

Comment: Or you can try and peer into this answer for a hint at how to do what you're looking to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692633/how-to-show-loading-gif-while-iframe-is-loading-up-a-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On submit you can show an loading image with javascript.
Put `onclick="showLoading()"` attribute into your submit button, and create a showLoading() javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 options: 
either ajax call the script, and than run some js on client side that shows progress
or you can in php return a response and continue execution with my following snippet

```
/*
 * basically allow a php script to return a response and continue with
 * code execution, good for statistics.
 * before echo anything to user call begin and after call end, than you can continue doing stuff
 */
class ScriptContinuationManager
{
    /**
     * this is the point where we need to give a sign to this class
     * that we wanna write our response.
     * @return void
     */
    public function beginRespone()
    {
        ob_end_clean();
        header("Connection: close");
        ignore_user_abort(); // optional
        ob_start();

    }

    /*
     * after this function execution the response will be sent to the
     * client, and code continue without client need to wait.
     */
    public function endResponse()
    {
        $size = ob_get_length();
        header("Content-Length: $size");
        ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
        flush(); // Unless both are called !

    }
}
```

Comment: There are benefits to the server side implementations, you don't always control of who calls you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a javascript solution:

This will hide the submit button and show an image in place. You need to choose a loading image yourself, you can generate one at http://ajaxload.info/ . Also you will have to give the form an ID attribute, and put it in the script.

(Make sure jQuery is included)

```
var formid = ''; // What is the ID of the form? (without the #)
var imgpath = ''; // What is the path to the loading image you want to display?

$(document).ready(function(event){  
    $('#'+ formid).submit(function(event){
        $('#'+ formid +' input[type=submit]').after('<img src="'+ imgpath +'">').hide();
    });
});
```

Edit: Also i suggest using AJAX methods, but looking at the writing style of your post i don't think you're that advanced.